# Bundle install error with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rbenv

I have been working through the Ruby on [Rails 3 Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), and recently switched from RVM to rbenv, per a recommendation from a Rubyist friend of mine.

Unfortunately, now when I create a new project and then attempt to `$ bundle install` I get this error:

```
/Users/alexanderdiner/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval': /Users/alexanderdiner/rails_projects/sample_app/Gemfile:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
gem 'sqlite...3.2.3'ygems.org' 
...                               ^ (SyntaxError)
```

I have been readin through some rbenv docs and such, but still struggling to find the issue here. For reference, the gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1' 
  gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4' 
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end
group :test do
 gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
 gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
 gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
 gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

Comment: @RyanBigg I changed it and I'm receiving the same error. So.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1' gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4' gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end
```

to

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1' 
  gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end
```

It should be enough.

Comment: I made this change and am still receiving the same error as before.

Comment: What's the output of `ruby -c Gemfile`? Here is `Syntax OK`, just tried. So there should be something else.

Comment: The output is: `Gemfile:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
gem 'sqlite...3.2.3'ygems.org'
...                               ^`

Comment: @Alexander: Please update your `Gemfile` again. It looks like it has a serious syntax error. If you have already posted it here, please considering posting it on http://gist.github.com.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an unprintable character in your Gemfile. Rename it, then create a new one using the contents you posted in your question.